# Magento 2: Hide action button by ACL rule in XML definition (ui component)

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, acl

I have added action button to the customer form (`vendor/module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="btnAccounting" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Customer\Adminhtml\Edit\AccountingButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</form>
```

but I need to hide this button by ACL rule.

Can I do it in this XML definition or should I use `\Magento\Framework\Authorization` (implements `\Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface`) class to do it in the button code (`\Vendor\Module\Block\Customer\Adminhtml\Edit\AccountingButton`):

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $registry);
    $this->authorization = $context->getAuthorization();
}

public function getButtonData()
{
    $isAllowed = $this->authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_Module::access_rule');
    if ($isAllowed) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Have you got solution? I need help with this.

Comment: @jack, I did it in the PHP code - https://github.com/flancer32/mage2_ext_login_as/blob/master/Block/Customer/Adminhtml/Edit/LoginAsButton.php#L34

Comment: thanks for your reply. In my case button on order view page added through plugin. Also, in mass action added through xml file.

I want to set ACl for both. Is there any way you know we can set ACL for both?

Comment: sorry, I know this method only.